# React: access component function from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just picked up a React project from someone else but I'm new to React so struggling a bit!

I have a file `ReactReport.js` that looks like this (simplified):

```
var ReportRoute = React.createClass({
  onToggleEditor: function() {
    this.setState({
      reportIsOpen: false
    });
  },
  getReportClassNames: function() {
    return classNames({
      'blinds--report-closed' : !this.state.reportIsOpen 
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className={this.getReportClassNames()}>
        <!-- content -->
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = ReportRoute;
```

I have a separate file `index.js` which contains a click event. In my `onChange` function I want to trigger the `onToggleEditor` function from the `ReportRoute` class.

```
var Categories = React.createClass({
  onChange: function(category) {
    // trigger ReportRoute.onToggleEditor();
  },
  renderCategory: function(category) {
    return (
      <Category
        category={category}
        chosenType={this.props.chosenType}
        key={category.type}
        onChange={this.onChange} />
    );
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.categories.map(this.renderCategory)}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Categories;
```

How do I trigger the `onToggleEditor` function from `ReportRoute` from within the `onChange` function of `Categories`?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use flux architecture for React to make inter component communication.
There are many implmentations of flux .
1.reflux 
2. redux

Basically in categories onChange, you will trigger a action.

```
onChange: function() {
  ReportActions.toggleEditor()
}
```

And your ReportRoute will be bind to a store.
Please check this example 
https://blog.ochronus.com/react-js-reflux-example-2d46a4d8faf0#.wcarr7oqt

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Refs. The short answer is to have a myRefs property on your Categories class and then add the following to you Category tag.

```
ref={ref => this.myRefs.push(ref)}
```

You can then call the first handler with.

```
this.myRefs[0].onToggleEditor()
```

Much more detail on this link.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html